# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'error' of undefined react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I need help with this . I am creating a registration form and getting the error cannot read property 'error' of undefined

```
 const handleSubmit = () => {
        const user = {
          email: {email},
          password: {password}
       }
        create(user).then((data) => {
          if (data.error) { 
            setValues({ ...values, error: data.error})
          } else {
            setValues({ ...values, error: '', open: true})
        }
      }) 
    setRedirect(true);
```

Comment: Did u check the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `data` variable is `undefined`, so u cannot access the property `error` of it. Do a `console.log(data)` before `if (data.error)` and check the `createUser` function what is outputting.